# Отображение в TreeView коллекции с двумя вложенными списками у каждого элемента коллекции

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть коллекция объектов типа Model:

```
public class Model
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ErrorModel> ErrorsList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<StandardModel> StandardsList { get; set; }
  }
 public class ErrorModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SecondaryError> SecondaryErrors { get; set; }        
  }
 public class StandardModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SecondaryStandards> SecondaryStandards { get; set; }        
  }
```

Задача: отобразить это в TreeView (чтобы можно было сворачивать ненужные элементы), как то так:
[image: концепт]
пробовал через `HierarchialDataTemplate`,но свойство `ItemSource` позволяет установить только один список (или `ErrorsList` или `StadardsList`)

пробовал так:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                      <Grid>...</Grid>
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErrorsList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorsListTemplate}"></ListView>
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StandardsList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardListTemplate}"></ListView>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

В данном случае теряем способность корневых элементов сворачиваться.
Можно наверное нагородить свой expander и обычный `ListView`, но может способ попроще есть?

Comment: Возможно вам нужен не TreeView, а обычный ItemsControl или ListBox с Expander в шаблоне элемента, в котором, в свою очередь, будет Grid с двумя ItemsControl

Comment: *Можно наверное нагородить свой expander и обычный ListView, но может способ попроще есть?* — ага, то что нужно, не дочитал до конца сразу. Куда уж проще? :)